# Paths to Screenshot Directory

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to find out the path of the screenshot directory of an Android device? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Otherwise I'm trying to make a list of possible paths and check in each path to find out the screenshot directory. So, what are the list of paths for the screenshot directory?

I already know these paths.

- *"/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots"*
- *"/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Screenshots"*
- *"/mnt/sdcard/ScreenCapture"*

Comment: how do you take a screenshot and on what range of devices ?

Comment: I'm not taking screenshots programmatically. I just want to find the screenshots saving directory. Range is 2.3 and above.

Comment: how to you take the screenshot ? Using buil-in capabilities, i.e. with hardware volume keys ? on 4.0 and above screenshots will be put in gallery, try fetch if from there. If you take them with some other 3d party program - see the description of that soft it should mention where it saves screens

Answer (score 0):

I just open myfile in andorid and went to screeshot folder and on the top it displayed the path see the picture on the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_CP5fn_tuEDcU5wTDVXZ3lwUjQ/edit?usp=sharing

for me the path was: "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots"

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get the path programmatically.

Comment: this may varies device to device.

Answer (score 0):

It is Difficult to decide the same.

e.g /mnt/sdcard this may differ from device to device

As per my suggestion use FileObserver(work when new file created ) it will give you path according to device .
    onEvent(int event, String path)method work when new file created in the device you simply  check the String path, if it contains String like Screenshots,Screen Capture then it points to screenshot directory then split the path according to requirement.

i am not sure but if it works mark it as solve so it helps other to find the ralevent answer.

Comment: I'm not clear much your suggestion. But as I understood, I have to make a screenshot to get the path. Isn't it ? But there are apps like this(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.screenshoteasy), which detects the screenshot directory. I'm looking for a solution like that.

Comment: Environment.getDataDirectory() gives you a root path now make a recursive function that checks the directories names of its sub directories.if a directory name is like "Screen" then get the path of this directory  and this is what you want.

Comment: That would be a good idea. Can you provide any sample code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

ok you dont have to make a screen shot to get the path just follow this step

app drawer > my file > all files > Pictures > Screenshots  and on the top of the first file you should be able to see the path.

Hope I answered your question